# Tradução da rejeição na análise de edições

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

O site está a ficar de novo em EN lol.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parece que esse texto foi atualizado no SOen e veio automaticamente para o SOpt, [segundo o blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/?cb=1)

Comment: Acabei de traduzir tudo. Quando for pro ar vou tentar lembrar de botar uma screenshot aqui com as traduções pra vocês recriminarem tudo :D

Comment: Faz isso ai gabe :D

Comment: Na parte de avaliação para questões indicadas ao fechamento, no motivo, também está em inglês.